# How do I store user profile data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a `user table` which `contains` the `user registration details` such as `username`, `password` and `email`...

How can I `add` a `profile table` to `store` `name, country, age etc`... ?

Do I simply `create` the `table` and `use JOIN` to select the data or `is there another way to do this` using `Ruby on Rails`?

Comment: Does the profile table necessarily have to be separate? The attributes you're talking about sound like they could be contained within the user table without it being a huge deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a migration to add those columns to the user model. From the sounds of it I don't think you would actually need a separate model for those attributes.

your migration might look something like

```
rails g migration AddProfileDataToUsers

class AddProfileDataToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.add_column :name, :string
    t.add_column :country, :string...
    #whatever else you want to add to the user model here
    end
end
```

Then you can pull the data as you need it by doing @user.country or something along those lines. Hope this helps

Comment: your approach was the one that came to my mind but what if i want to store other than what i mentioned, background color, link color etc... and many other attributes such as invites count that could make the total new columns up to 10+-

Comment: @fxuser: That's more of a design decision rather than a purely technical one. You could go with tjkoding's suggestion and just add more columns as you see fit or you could make an entirely new model and just associate it with your user model. If you ask me, I would just add more columns.

Comment: ill go with the new table and associate it with my user model... if i wanted to add 3-4 new columns i would do what @tjkoding says but since my user model has over 15 columns i don't think adding 10+ more will be easily manageable...